# eclipse does not respect suppression.xml file from maven-checkstyle-plugin

Tags: eclipse, checkstyle, maven-checkstyle-plugin

I've using the `maven-checkstyle-plugin` (config see below) in version `3.2.1` for quite some time now and I'm also using a custom `checkstyle.xml` and `suppressions.xml`

e.g. in the `suppressions.xml` I have entries like:

```
<suppress files="messages.properties" checks="[a-zA-Z0-9]*"/>
<suppress files="target/generated-sources" checks=".*"/>
```

Since a few days, I see an error message in my eclipse (2023-03), e.g. in the above mentioned `message.properties` file:

```
(!) Line is longer then 120 characters (found xxx)
my.lang.key = a very long line with more then 120 chars, but this file should be ignored at all ...
```

The generated code in `target/generated-sources/...` is also clustered with checkstyle errors, although the files in this path should not be validated.

If I run a build on the console the build does not fail, hence the `plugin` is respecting the `suppression.xml` file, but the error flag in eclipse is still shown.

An update to `maven-checkstyle-plugin`:`3.2.2` and `checkstyle`:`10.11.0` (currently most recent versions) did not fix the problem.

Just another observation, I also have a new meta/config file in my project: `.checkstyle`, I suppose this is related ...?

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.2.1</version>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>acme</groupId>
        <artifactId>checkstyle-config-cms</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.puppycrawl.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
        <version>10.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<configuration>
    <configLocation>checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
    <suppressionsLocation>suppressions.xml</suppressionsLocation>
    <inputEncoding>UTF-8</inputEncoding>
    <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
    <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
    <linkXRef>false</linkXRef>
</configuration>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>validate</id>
        <phase>validate</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>check</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: i fear, you (still!?) need to configure it "twice" (once in maven, and once [here](https://checkstyle.org/eclipse-cs/)) ...  or use some (additional) "integration" (plugin) like [this](https://github.com/m2e-code-quality/m2e-code-quality)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, until now I did not come up with a better solution then to disable the checkstyle plugin within eclipse.

To do so, right click your project -> `Checkstyle` -> `Deactivate Checkstyle`

If the error is still shown you must clear your checkstyle violations.
The maven run is not affected by this change and still is using checkstyle correctly.

---

**Update** (2024/01/24):

As it turns out you can avoid this problem when importing a project into eclipse (I'm using currently version: 2023-12 - freshly installed).

When I import a clean `maven` project that is using the `checkstyle-maven-plugin` into eclipse. I get a pop-up asking to setup a `maven plugin connector`.

[image: maven-checkstyle-connector plugin]

> Install Applies configuration from the maven-checkstyle-plugin to the
> Eclipse Checkstyle plugin. Disables execution of the
> maven-checkstyle-plugin within Eclipse in favor of the Eclipse plugin.

You probably can skip/cancel this, BUT if you are adding in advance some eclipse meta data information (see eclipse [release-notes-17](https://eclipse.dev/m2e/documentation/release-notes-17.html#new-syntax-for-specifying-lifecycle-mapping-metadata)), e.g. `<?m2e ignore?>`

> A new syntax has been introduced to simplify lifecycle mapping
> metadata for plugin executions, using processing instructions within
> plugin/executions/execution nodes.

Eclipse will not ask you to take control of the `checkstyle` handling and most probably will not make the above mentioned problems.

```
...
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.3.1</version>
  <?m2e ignore?>
  ...
```